# How to read a property of LINQ using only a string?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have a field (HTML input text) where my user can input the name of property he wants, like: "name". With this value, I need to return the value of property Name on my object.
By the way, I must achieve a depth property, something like User.Contact.PhoneNumber if the user type Contact.PhoneNumber. Can I do that?

I'm using LINQ, so the object User is lazyloaded. The property Contact must be or not loaded yet.

Here what I'm trying now:

```
ParameterExpression input = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User));
var expr = Expression.Property(input, typeof(User).GetProperty("Name"));
var justatest = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, string>>(expr, input).Compile();
```

Comment: What is your current code? Do you tried something?

Comment: I'm trying a ParameterExpression type, but got stucked. I'll put in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think getting a property of a property, such as User.Contact.PhoneNumber could get difficult. You would need to have nested PropertyExpressions for as deep as the statement goes.

Maybe the dynamic linq library would make it easier for you:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/

Comment: Nice, I'll give it a try! Come back here to accept as answer if it works.

Comment: Maybe I'm using it wrong, but its for Dynamic Query. I already have an object. I just need to ready the property value of this object. Any other hint?